# Given an inequality on the $\limsup$ of the infimums of functions, construct a sequence of points matching it

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, limsup-and-liminf

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, and let $f$ be a real valued function defined on $X$. Let $f_n$ be a sequence of real valued functions defined on $X$.

Fix $u \in X$

Assume that for every $\delta > 0, \limsup_{j\to\infty} \inf\{f_j(v): d(u,v) <\delta \} \leq f(u)$

Then, the claim is that there exists a sequence $\{u_j\}$ which converges to $u$ in $X$ such that
$$\limsup_{j\to\infty} f_j(u_j) \leq f(u) $$

---

To prove the claim, here is wht I tried:

Let $u_n$ such that

$$f_n(u_n) < \inf \{f_n(v): d(u,v) < \frac{1}{n} \} + \frac{1}{n} $$ Then, I took the limsup of both sides, but then my "delta" $\frac{1}{n}$ shrunk to zero, so I cannot conclude what I want.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

The problem becomes more transparent if it is recast in terms of the *epigraph* of $f_j$, which is the set 
$$E_j = \{(v,y): y\ge f_j(v) \}\subset X\times \mathbb{R}$$ 
The given condition says: for every $\epsilon>0$ and every $\delta>0$, for all large enough $j$ there is a point  $(v,y)\in E_j$ such that $d(u,v)<\delta$ and $y = f(u)+\epsilon$.  (Indeed, this is saying that $f_j(v)\le f(u)+\epsilon$.)

We can simplify this by using $\epsilon=\delta$, and  then reword the assumption concisely as 
$$\operatorname{dist}((u,f(u)), E_j)\to 0 \tag{1}$$ 
(This refers to a metric on the   product $X\times \mathbb{R}$; for example the metric $\rho ((v,y),(w,z)) = d(v,w) + |y-z|$ will do.)

Now the solution is immediate: pick a point $(v_j,y_j)\in E_j$ such that 
$$\rho( (u,f(u)), (v_j,y_j)) < \operatorname{dist}((u,f(u)),E_j) +\frac1j  $$
Then $\rho( (u,f(u)), (v_j,y_j))\to 0$, which implies both $v_j\to u$ and $\limsup f(v_j) \le f(u)$.

Comment: I don't understand the part that begins with " The given condition says:..". How do I know that there is a point in $E_j$?

Comment: Expanded to clarify.

Comment: What I do not understand is that the given condition is for the limsup of inf of $f_j$ over the $\delta$ neighborhood of $u$. So, all I can deduce is that for any $\epsilon$ and any $\delta$, for all large enough j, $\inf \{f_j(u): d(u,v) < \delta \} \leq f(u) + \epsilon$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Use $\epsilon/2$ here: $\inf \{f_j(u): d(u,v) < \delta \} \leq f(u) + \epsilon/2$, then there is $v$ such that $f_j(v)\le f(u)+\epsilon$.

Comment: I understand it now. My last question is, can you explain to me how you get $\limsup f(v_j) \leq f(u)$ in your last sentence?

Comment: From $y_j\to f(u)$ and $f(v_j)\le y_j$.

Comment: thank you very much for your patience :)